# DataGridView for loop error

Tags: datagridview

Considering the following code:

Public Class CrewDatabaseForm

```
Public Shared CrewList As List(Of String)

Private Sub CrewDatabaseForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Dim CL As New List(Of String)
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 2 Then CL.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value)
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 2 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To (DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)
            CL.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString)
        Next
    End If
    MessageBox.Show(DataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString)


End Sub


Private Sub CrewDatabaseForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

--This form is only a datagridview.  Whenever I exit the form, and the if and for statements commence, if I have entered a value in the first column and not pressed enter an error occurs:

"An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Stage Tally.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

Comment: Clearly there's a `null` reference in your code at runtime.  Notice that you're explicitly referencing things like `DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0)` without checking if `Rows` or `Cells` even have anything in them.  When you run this in a debugger, inspect the values of the variables you're using when the exception occurs.  One of them is `null`.

Comment: Thanks dude!! So basically check if it is null first, then do the for loop?

Comment: What would that look like?  How do I say if = null in vb.net language please?

Comment: I think in VB it might be something like: `If SomeValue <> Nothing Then`